# How to get the RsaSecurityKey from Base64 public key in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: .net, blazor, webassembly

I have some client side code that validates a custom JWT, which is signed with RSA private key and using the given Base64 public RSA key for validation. This all works fine in console app and Blazor Server but `RSACryptoProvider` fails in Blazor WASM.

**The questions I have are:**

1. Is there another way than to obtain the signing key from the Base64 public key for token validation?
2. Is token validation with asymmetric key possible anyway in Blazor WASM?

**Some more background:**
My code uses .Net 6 standard RSA cryptography via:

```cs
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(); 
>>>Previous line throws exception but following lines are included for context<<<

rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(Convert.FromBase64String(TokenPublicKeyBase64), out _);
new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
{
  ... 
  IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa), 
  ...
}
```

The exception I get when `RSACryptoProvider` is instantiated is `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`. This exception is by design but I could not find another standard method to obtain the IssuesSigning key for the token validation.

Edit 1: For clarity, the keys are generated on the server so there is no need to create client-side keypairs.

Comment: Note that token validation in a SPA is [not very useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#validate-the-id-token)

Comment: Point taken but the idea is that for offline use some validation is better than no validation as the token may be stored locally. Everything stored locally can be hacked but that's for another topic :)